# why reload page in next js && error bug 404?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a project and I have two components called home , about components.
When I'm on the home component and I'm going to the about component everything all right
but When I'm on the about component and Reload the page again error not found(404).
what?

Comment: Can you post `your code`  or a `codesandbox.io` link ?

Comment: Do you have a NodeJS backend which also taking care of routing?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is, on your first load (at home component), client receive the whole ReactJS App and the routing from that point will be handled by ReactJS App (client routing). In your second case, you are at the about (component) and reload the app, the request send to the server like `.../about` and no route on server match it then it returns 404.

P/S: Follow along with Next official tutorial, you will face that case and they explain quite clear about it.

https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started